# Remove matching words from the string using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to remove the words Z or ZN and LVT from the strings present in my file but I couldn't get it. Can someone check my code.

Input

```
abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)
asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)
shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
```

Output

```
abchsfk/jshflka                     cell
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf                 mob
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf     cel
asjhdjs/jhskjds                     abc
shdsjk/jhskd                        xyz
```

CODE:

```
     if ($line =~ /LVT/ && ($line =~ /ZN/ || $line =~ /Z/) )        

        ####  matches the words LVT and ( Z or ZN)

        {   
             my @names = split / /, $line;      ##### splits the line 


                $names[2] =~ s/\/Z|/ZN//g;      #### remove Z or ZN 
                $names[3] =~ s/\(|LVT\)//g ;  #### remove LVT & braces

                print OUT " $names[2] $names[3] \n";    #### print 

         }
```

Comment: Why not just `$line =~ s/\/ZN?|LVT//g;`

Comment: @sln. Thank you. I want to remove the "/Z" and "/ZN" together instead of just Z or ZN. and I want to remove the braces also. So i tried to split it first and then try removing it one by one.

Comment: @sln. I tried this way from the idea you gave. it worked for me.  
            `$line =~ s/\/ZN?|\(|LVT\)//g;`

Comment: That regex does that, but if you want to include parens with it, this works `$line =~ s/[()]|\/ZN?|LVT//g;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of matching: `s/\/Z|\/ZN//g` (the second backslash is missing in your code!). You should match the longer string first, otherwise Z will match and N won't be deleted.

There's even easier way, though: Just use `\/ZN?`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /LVT/ && $line =~ /ZN?/) {

        my @names = split ' ', $line;
        $names[0] =~ s/\/ZN?//g;
        $names[1] =~ s/\(|LVT\)//g;
        print "$names[0] $names[1]\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)
asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobLVT)
asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)
asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcLVT)
shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzLVT)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. its really helpful

Comment: I have one more question to ask in this. In my output. Some of the lines are repeated. I want to sort them and print them only once. Can I use sort function. Here is what I am trying

`while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /LVT/ && $line =~ /ZN?/) {`

       my @names = split ' ', $line;
        $names[0] =~ s/\/ZN?//g;
        $names[1] =~ s/\(|LVT\)//g;

         my @line_out = "$names[0] $names[1]";

          $lvt_out = sort::$line_out(); 
          print "$lvt_out\n";
      }`

Comment: @SKG: You should ask a new question in a, um, new question.